# fast api - await websocket.receive_text(())

Tags: python, fastapi

the async function is here it establishes a player when a websocket connection is created. The player has a function of placing a bet that eventually feeds into a Table class that executes a game of poker:

```html
class Player():
    def __init__(self,name,buy,websocket):
        self.name=name
        self.balance=float(buy)
        self.hand=[]
        self.currentbet=0
        self.handscore=0
        self.websocket=websocket
    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'player {self.name}')
    async def placebettest(self, current_price, valid=True):
        await self.websocket.send_text(f'{self.name}, price is {current_price},             Invalid Bet Size, what is your new bet (0 for check, -1 for fold): ')
        print('waiting on bet')
        bet = float(await self.websocket.receive_text())
        print(bet)
        #return bet
```

the app.py code is here, right now i am able to add players and setup the table without a problem. The only issue is when i introduce the placebet and placebettest functions and attempt to gather text responses from the client:

```html
@app.websocket("/ws/{user_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(user_id: str, websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    global table
    
    #add players
    
    #await websocket.send_text('enter number of players')
    #numplayers=await websocket.receive_text()
    #await websocket.send_text('enter your buy-in amount')
    #buyamount=await websocket.receive_text()
    #print(buyamount)
    #user_id=Player(user_id,buyamount,websocket)
    #connected_users[user_id] = websocket
    #print(connected_users)
    
    #initialize game once button is pressed
    
    #print(len(connected_users))
    #if len(connected_users) == int(numplayers):
    #    global table
    #    await websocket.send_text('blind amounts seperated by comma')
    #    blinds=await websocket.receive_text()
    #    blinds=blinds.split(',')
    #    table = Table(blinds[0],blinds[1])
    #    for x in connected_users:
    #        table.addplayer(x)
    #    print(table.list)
    
    #TEST fixing table round setup
    # Initialize player and add to connected users
    player = Player(user_id, 20, websocket)
    connected_users[user_id] = player
    
    # Check if enough players have connected to start the game
    numplayers = 3  # Example: Change this according to your game requirements
    if len(connected_users) == numplayers:
        # Set up the table
        blinds = [0.1, 0.2]  # Example: Adjust according to your game rules
        table = Table(blinds[0], blinds[1])
        
        # Add players to the table
        for player in connected_users.values():
            table.addplayer(player)
        
        # Test the table setup
        print(table.order)
        table.pickdealer()
        for player in table.order:
            print(player.websocket)
        print(table.order)
        
        # Test player actions (place bets)
        for x in table.order:
            await x.placebettest(1)
```

The websocket is disconnecting or throwing an error when await x.placebettest(1) -> bet = await websocket.receive_text(())